# Question migrated to meta english

Tags: bug, status-completed, migrated-questions

Just now I accidentally posted a question here (meta.stackoverflow), where I should have posted to meta.english.stackexchange.com. It has beem [migrated](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2525).
It appears my account isn't linked, as the username isn't a link and I can't edit the question.

Do I need to repost the question and flag to close the migrated one, or is this something a mod can fix?

---

Also, what's wrong the the content as above, (does not meet our quality standards)?
See [original, unedited version](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/125748/revisions#reva34f7594-3744-4abf-b2a6-0858615570ce).

Comment: OT: Once i added the linebreak and last sentence i could post this, but without those it wouldn't let me.

Comment: You have some links without `http://` so maybe it's considered bad quality.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: line breaks could be it, not capitalizing `I` in English is a deathly sin, and possibly those partial urls don't help.

Comment: Can you link to the question?

Comment: @Jim: Sorry, I should have done that originally. [Would this question be on topic?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/2525)

Comment: Sorry about that.  I looked and saw you had an active account on E&LU, so I assumed the migration would work to that site's Meta.

Comment: Bug found and is being squashed. The migrated post should be associated with your account on Meta English now. :)

Comment: @Anna, thanks. And thanks to everyone else involved. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just flag the migrated question and indicate that it should be linked to your account.

Comment: Accepted as it answers the question (What do I do?).

Answer (score 2):

The question [is already migrated](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2525/would-this-question-be-on-topic) but the bug is that it didn't identify the accout association:

[image: migration bug]

The weird part - your accounts **are** associated:

[image: association]

Maybe Bill (the moderator who migrated the question) can shed some light, hope he see this post.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm confused about (should have mentioned it's already migrated). Also, is there some way to have my profile page look like the above image permanently? I like the free-hand circle, especially because of it's non-standard colour.

Comment: @George what you mean by "look like the above image permanently"? As for the color it was mistake actually intended to choose Blue but clicked one color below. Appears to be `#00137F` lol :)

Comment: I was just joking that I want my profile page to have a free-hand circle, like in the image in your post. :)

Comment: Lol, thought you meant for example having the "Accounts" tab opened by default. :)